# How to create new Pandas Dataframe with columns form DataFrame (PYTHON)

Tags: pandas

I am creating a DataFrame from a csv file, where my index (rows) is date and my column names are names of cities.

After I create the raw DataFrame, I am trying to create a DataFrame from selected columns. I have tried:

```
A=df['city1'] #city 1
B=df['city2']
C=pd.merge(A,B)
```

but it does't work. This is what A and B look like.

```
    Date
2013-11-01     2.56
2013-12-01     1.77
2014-01-01     0.00
2014-02-01     0.38
2014-03-01    13.16
2014-04-01    10.29
2014-05-01    15.43
2014-06-01    11.48
2014-07-01     8.54
2014-08-01    11.11
2014-09-01     2.71
2014-10-01     4.16
2014-11-01    13.01
2014-12-01     9.59
Name: Seattle.Washington, dtype: float64 Date
```

And this is what I am looking to create:

```
                    City1                   City2 
Date                                                              
2013-11-01           0.00                   2.94          
2013-12-01           8.26                   3.41          
2014-01-01           1.11                  14.27              
2014-02-01          32.86                  84.26           
2014-03-01          34.12                   0.00          
2014-04-01          68.39                   0.00         
2014-05-01          27.17                   9.09          
2014-06-01          10.47                  32.00          
2014-07-01          14.19                  26.83          
2014-08-01          14.91                   6.36          
2014-09-01           3.76                   8.32             
2014-10-01           5.83                   2.19         
2014-11-01          10.79                   2.64          
2014-12-01          21.24                   8.08
```

Any suggestion?

Error Message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-222-ec50ff9f372f> in <module>()
     14 S = df['City1']
     15 A = df['City2']
     16 
---> 17 print merge(S,A)
     18 #df2=pd.merge(A,A)
     19 #print df2

C:\...\merge.pyc in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy)
     36                          right_on=right_on, left_index=left_index,
     37                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
---> 38                          copy=copy)
     39     return op.get_result()
     40 if __debug__:
```

Comment: Well you've not specified what doesn't work, my guess here is that the result is not what you desired but you've not stated what your desired output should look like. Are you trying to merge based on the index?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to merge by index. In this case index=date.I have tried append, but that seems to concatenate.

Comment: In that case you should do `pd.merge(df['City1'], df['City2'], left_index=True, right_index=True)` but I'm confused it looks like you are just selecting 'City1' and 'City2' columns from the same df, in which why not just do `df[['City1', 'City2']]`?

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that already! Just tried df[['City1', 'City2']] and it  worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answer: (Courtesy of @EdChum)

```
df[['City1', 'City2']]
```